# FlutterFlow ' Nan ' with code expression. how can i solve it?

Tags: nan, flutterflow

[[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wK95d.png)][[code expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waRtl.png)]

After setting two variables in the app state, when I fetch and calculate these two variables in the code expression, NaN is output as shown in the picture. After testing various conditions, it seems that this issue occurs only when performing 'division' calculations with app state variables. Is there a solution to this?

NaN is only output when 0 is assigned to a variable within the app state, and entering a non-zero number yields a different result.